# create google map with users location with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I'm new to React and currently trying to learn how to use `react-google-maps` library. Tried to show a map with users geolocation as the `initialCenter` of the map.

This is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { GoogleApiWrapper, Map } from "google-maps-react";

export class MapContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { userLocation: { lat: 32, lng: 32 } };
  }
  componentWillMount(props) {
    this.setState({
      userLocation: navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        this.renderPosition
      )
    });
  }
  renderPosition(position) {
    return { lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        initialCenter={this.state.userLocation}
        zoom={10}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "-----------"
})(MapContainer);
```

Insted of creating a map with users location I get an `initialCenter` of my default state values.

How can I fix it? Am I even using the lifecycle function right?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, so you need to use the success callback and set the user location in there.

You could add an additional piece of state named e.g. `loading`, and only render when the user's geolocation is known.

**Example**

```
export class MapContainer extends React.Component {
  state = { userLocation: { lat: 32, lng: 32 }, loading: true };

  componentDidMount(props) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;

        this.setState({
          userLocation: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude },
          loading: false
        });
      },
      () => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, userLocation } = this.state;
    const { google } = this.props;

    if (loading) {
      return null;
    }

    return <Map google={google} initialCenter={userLocation} zoom={10} />;
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "-----------"
})(MapContainer);
```

Comment: one more question - why did you used ComponentDidMount and not WillMount? I thought that DidMount supposed to be called when I want to do something before the render and as I understand here I'm making a call to getCurrentLocation after the component renders..

Comment: @arikm9 `componentWillMount` is `UNSAFE` in the latest version of React. You can [read more about it here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount). For your use case however, it doesn't really matter since `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous and you can't do anything before the component mounts anyway.